# Regex (or alternative method) to remove content of a specfic tag in a HTML document

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to build a RegEx string for use in a find and replace in sublime text or notepad++ to remove strikethrough text from a html page. In general, the strikethrough is formatted as follows:

```
<span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"><s>Some text here</s></span>
```

So far, I've come up with this:

```
<span.*<s>.*<\/s><\/span>
```

But it doesn't stop at the first `</span>`, it continues on so I get a huge slab of text selected. I've had a look at the regex wiki (and several other resources), and I'm sure this is a "greedy matches" issue, but I can't get my head around what that should look like.

Edit: I'm not set on RegEx by the way, if anyone has a better solution of how to achieve what I'm after I'm all ears

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @maxzoom: He's *not* trying to parse an HTML document, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to limit a greedy match is to make it stop at a specific character. `[abc]` is a character class meaning any of a, b, c, while `[^abc]` means anything but a, b, c. So `[^<]` means anything but `<`.

```
<span[^>]*><s>[^<]*</s></span>
```

The other (much slower) way is to set the `*` or `+` operator to return the shortest match. In Perl-compatible regex, you do this with `*?` or `+?`.

Comment: Works perfectly, a million thankyous! Will mark this as the correct answer when the time limit allows :)

Comment: Your first regex won't work if there are other tags in the strikeout, e.g. `<span><s>first <b>second</b> third</s></span>`.  (The second strategy will work in this case.)

Comment: True, if there are other nested tags then it may be better to use `.*?` between the strikeout tags.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on dwks's answer and the comments on it, if there are any HTML tags at all inside the struck-through text, e.g. if it looks like

```
<span><s>first <b>second</b> third</s></span>
```

then it won't match the regex

```
<span[^>]*><s>[^<]*</s></span>
```

since this regex won't stand for a `<` between the `<s>` and `</s>`.  At the end of the answer it's mentioned that you can use `*?`.  For the sake of completeness, that regex would look something like this:

```
<span[^>]*><s>.*?<\/s><\/span>
```

Comment: Perhaps `[^>]*>` or `.*?` instead of `.*` in the last example

Comment: Yeah, that's reasonable.  (Updated answer to include suggestion.)